# when will .m2/repository folder gets created in linux for maven 2

Tags: maven-2, jenkins

I've unzipped maven 2 package, set the M2_Home, M2, PATH variables and tested maven with mvn --version ...I dont see .m2/repository folder created.
I've edited settings.xml in conf folder adding some profiles for nexus. when I run a job in jenkins. It fails and it doesn't download any dependencies from nexus and still no repository folder is created in .m2 directory

let me know whats going wrong here

Answer (score 2):

Check here
`/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/`

Answer (score -2):

In most cases you just need to go to your project main directory (the one with master pom.xml) and run the following command:

```
mvn clean install
```

It will by default download any necessary artifacts into your local maven repository creating the folders if does not exist yet.